# UnauthorizedAccessException with Unicorn

Tags: unicorn

Environment details:
Unicorn: 4.1.4
Sitecore: 10.1.1

While de-serializing the item, for a particular item I am getting the following exception

```
ERROR: Some directories could not be loaded. (1 inner failures)
master:{{Item-path}} {{Item-id}} (Unicorn.DeserializationAggregateException)
at Unicorn.Loader.DeserializeFailureRetryer.RetryAll(ISourceDataStore sourceDataStore, Action`1 retrySingleItemAction, Action`1 retryTreeAction)
   at Unicorn.Loader.SerializationLoader.LoadAll(IItemData[] rootItemsData, IDeserializeFailureRetryer retryer, IConsistencyChecker consistencyChecker, Action`1 rootLoadedCallback)
   at Unicorn.SerializationHelper.SyncTree(IConfiguration configuration, Action`1 rootLoadedCallback, Boolean runSyncStartPipeline, IItemData partialSyncRoot)
   at Unicorn.SerializationHelper.SyncConfigurations(IConfiguration[] configurations, IProgressStatus progress, ILogger additionalLogger)

INNER EXCEPTION
master:{{Item-path}} {{Item-id}} (Rainbow.Storage.Sc.Deserialization.DeserializationException)
No stack trace available.
INNER EXCEPTION
Failed to paste item: {{Item-path}} (Rainbow.Storage.Sc.Deserialization.DeserializationException)
at Rainbow.Storage.Sc.Deserialization.DefaultDeserializer.Deserialize(IItemData serializedItemData, IFieldValueManipulator fieldValueManipulator)
   at Rainbow.Storage.Sc.SitecoreDataStore.Save(IItemData item, IFieldValueManipulator fieldValueManipulator)
   at Unicorn.Evaluators.NewItemOnlyEvaluator.EvaluateNewSerializedItem(IItemData newItemData)
   at Unicorn.Loader.SerializationLoader.DoLoadItem(IItemData serializedItemData, IConsistencyChecker consistencyChecker)
   at Unicorn.Loader.DeserializeFailureRetryer.RetryAll(ISourceDataStore sourceDataStore, Action`1 retrySingleItemAction, Action`1 retryTreeAction)
INNER EXCEPTION
The current user does not have write access to this item. User: extranet\Anonymous, Item: Heading Tag {{Item-id}} (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.BeginEdit()
   at Rainbow.Storage.Sc.Deserialization.DefaultDeserializer.PasteSharedFields(IItemData serializedItemData, Item targetItem, Boolean newItemWasCreated, List`1 softErrors, IFieldValueManipulator fieldValueManipulator)
   at Rainbow.Storage.Sc.Deserialization.DefaultDeserializer.Deserialize(IItemData serializedItemData, IFieldValueManipulator fieldValueManipulator)
```

I cannot find any security-related deviation from other items that are getting updated.
There has not been a similar exception in a lower environment. The issue has persisted in this environment even after multiple re-try.

Thanks.

Please suggest where we should look for it.

Comment: Did you check this article? https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/10/03/sitecore-unicorn-serialization-paths-too-long-in-azure/

Comment: The issue is going to keep on persisting until you resolve the error. `The current user does not have write access to this item. User: extranet\Anonymous`. This is a permissions (file system) issue, not a Unicorn issue. Also explains why it would not happen on lower environments.

Comment: @MarkCassidy: Sorry but I differ. Just after the line you have quoted, it mentions that the exception is thrown at BeginEdit() and it clearly mentions write access. So, I think should be while writing to the Sitecore.

Comment: @SumitBhatia: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, this is not the case here.

Comment: Seems strange that it is being run under extranet\anonymous. How are you running the sync? logged in as admin via unicorn.aspx or via powershell? If you temporarily give read/write access for extranet\anonymous to that one item and rerun sync, does it get past that part in the process?

Comment: @DeanOBrien: It is being executed through PowerShell. Extranet\anonymous already has access to the item in Sitecore.

Comment: The issue is the same as https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/issues/429